# How to put a shortcut to a settings submenu on a home screen

Tags: settings, home-screen, home-screen-shortcuts

Use case:
 I would like to change the input language for voice input without having to click through 
 "Settings/voice input and output/voice recognition settings/Language" 
 And I have a couple of similar ones resulting in the same question:
Is there a way to place a shortcut to a particular submenu of the settings on a home screen?
Another (even better) option would be to tie a praticular setting to a custom keyboard shortcut.

Am I expecting too much?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Manual Intent Shortcuts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.cwfk.ig88.intents).
It offers to add a custom launcher widget that sends intents defined by you.

To launch the VoiceSearch Settings window, do the following:

- add a new "manual intents shortcut" widget to your home screen
- enter a name
- Action = "android.intent.action.MAIN"
- Component Package = "com.google.android.voicesearch"
- Component Class (FQDN) = "com.google.android.voicesearch.VoiceSearchPreferences"

Leave all other fields empty, uncheck "broadcast"

You now have a shortcut to the settings window you want.

PS: I used apktool to inspect the AndroidManifest.xml in VoiceSearch.apk (system app, you need root to access it) which lists this Activity.

Comment: This is the only working solution and the only one with a real explanation. Many thanks, ce4.

Comment: Nice to know you appreciate it and got it working (some  time has passed since you asked it, hehe)! Alas, it's not easy to find the params (needs serious power user skills) but once you got them it's easy.

Comment: @ce4 Any idea how to get to SIM management/SIM INFORMATION/{specific sim} and switch to turn it on/off (I have dual sim phone)?

Comment: @Piotr: Alas, no. I don't have a dual-sim phone. Maybe look at logcat output?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible to add a shortcut to a settings menu, but probably not as "deep" as you'd like.

Long-press on a screen and select "Shortcut" in the menu that pops up. Then choose "Settings" and then the settings menu you want.

Comment: Unfortunately you're right. The "add shortcut" method features only a ridiculously narrow selection of settings...takes some wind off my sails, but thanks anyway. Could one do it programmatically? I could whip up an app doing exactly that then.

Comment: Check the market for apps/widgets that make it easier to get to your settings. "Quick Settings" was one that I've used in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: [Gesture Search](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.gesturesearch)

It searches contacts, apps, bookmarks, files, and **settings**. By the time you scrawl out `V O I` you should probably see the voice setting you need.

Comment: Nice idea, but the deepest setting i get proposed is the "voice input and output". I experimented for some time...so I'm afraid deeper settings just dont make it into the index. So it even takes me half a second more to reach the language settings. But GS is still a very useful app I wasnt aware of, so +1

Answer (score 1):

Supplemental answer to @ce4's answer which is correct. In Android Marshmallow 6.0, it would be these values for Manual Intent Shortcuts:

- Action = "android.intent.action.MAIN"
- Component Package = "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox"
- Component Class (FQDN) = "com.google.android.apps.gsa.velvet.ui.settings.VoiceSearchPreferences"

I would just add these to his comment, but I don't have reputation to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I was with a similar problem. I was trying to launch the Adapt Sound configuration. Samsung removed the Settings widget from its phones, so you won't find it.

I solved using the [Shotcut Maker app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rk.android.app.shortcutmaker). My desired shortcut was inside the "Activities" options. Now I can quickly get to this sub sub sub Settings option.